# How can I create a graph in python (pyqtgraph) where verticies display images?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I would like to construct an interactive graph (as in G = (V, E) with vertices and edges) using python, and I would like to display images on top of each vertex.

I'm using this to visualize a medium to large sized clustering problem, so I'd like whatever backend I use preferably be very fast (so networkx doesnt seem to cut it).

I'm basically looking for creating a set of verticies and assigning an image (or path to an image, or function to create an image) to each. Then I want to specify connections between verticies and their weights.

Its not the end of the world if I have to specify positions of each vertex, but ideally I'd like a layout to be automatically generated using the weights on the graphs.

It would also be cool if I could move the nodes with my mouse, but again, not the end of the world if I have to build that in myself. I just need to get to a starting point.

I was using this demo code to build a graph.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

# Enable antialiasing for prettier plots
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

w = pg.GraphicsWindow()
w.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: GraphItem')
v = w.addViewBox()
v.setAspectLocked()

g = pg.GraphItem()
v.addItem(g)

## Define positions of nodes
pos = np.array([
    [0,0],
    [10,0],
    [0,10],
    [10,10],
    [5,5],
    [15,5]
    ])

## Define the set of connections in the graph
adj = np.array([
    [0,1],
    [1,3],
    [3,2],
    [2,0],
    [1,5],
    [3,5],
    ])

## Define the symbol to use for each node (this is optional)
symbols = ['o','o','o','o','t','+']

## Define the line style for each connection (this is optional)
lines = np.array([
    (255,0,0,255,1),
    (255,0,255,255,2),
    (255,0,255,255,3),
    (255,255,0,255,2),
    (255,0,0,255,1),
    (255,255,255,255,4),
    ], dtype=[('red',np.ubyte),('green',np.ubyte),('blue',np.ubyte),('alpha',np.ubyte),('width',float)])

## Update the graph
g.setData(pos=pos, adj=adj, pen=lines, size=1, symbol=symbols, pxMode=False)
```

I tried chaning symbols to use a pyqtgraph image item, but that did not seem to work.

```
# My Code to make an image
img = ibs.get_annot_chips(cm.qaid)
img_item = pg.ImageItem(img)
# ....
# breaks...
symbols = [img_item,'o','o','o','t','+']
```

Any input or advice on how to do this?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If so, what?

Answer (score 0):

PyQtGraph does not support this, but it would be a very nice feature. If you look in `graphicsItems/ScatterPlotItem.py`, near the top is a function called `renderSymbol()` which generates a QImage based on the symbol parameters specified by the user. You could probably modify this by adding:

```
if isinstance(symbol, QtGui.QImage):
    return symbol
```

to the top of the function and expect everything to work as you expect (you might need to correct some type checking elsewhere as well).